# UIAlert in threaded block not working with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, multithreading, afnetworking-2

I am using a subclass of AFHTTPSessionManager to make GET requests. I use GCD to send some processing of responseObject to a thread. If the responseObject returns no dictionaries, I want an alert, but this alert never shows. Is it the threading or is it an issue with the responseObject? If I check responseObject == nil, then it won't work because there must be some object even if it has no dictionaries in it since responseObject is of type "id". I think this is the issue but not sure since the threading is complicating things. Thanks.

```
[client GET:getString parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        {
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;
            if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    if (responseObject == nil){

                          [message show];

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is, you need to check class of responseObject:

```
[client GET:getString parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)task.response;
        if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
            if(![responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                      [message show];
           }
```